# PHP shell_exec different output

Tags: php, linux, shell

How it's possible that shell_exec give a different results than when the command is manually triggered?
I'm executing

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/wc --words ' . $filepath).
```

My PHP is 7.4.3 , 
I have also tried `wc -w`.
It gives a different output when is triggered manually from shell. 
I have tested it with webmaster user from shell and its running under webmaster user on web.
I have tested this with running `whoami`. It just doesn't make any sense. It doesn't give any errors or anything, it just gives different outputs.
When I run it with webmaster from shell it gives a regular ouput, eq. exact number of words.
Anyone have any idea where to look since I have already tried users and permissions?

Comment: Can you add an example of your filepath, the current output and the expected output to make it reproducible for us?

Comment: @ChristophKluge sure, 

its an abs filepath ie. /path/to/file/name.txt owned by webmaster from /to/ downwards including file.
Response is in correct format but with incorrect value ie. instead of 16022 it returns 1675 as number of words.

Comment: If you use `md5sum` instead of `/usr/bin/wc --words`, does it show a different checksum?

Comment: @thatotherguy MD5 hashes are same, I have just checked it.
I just don't get it.

Comment: How odd. The difference is actually 10x, and it's just a single file? Does `LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/wc --words` to use the same locale show a difference?

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes its just one file. I have tried it with `LC_ALL=C` and the result its same. 
Its an converted pdf from arabian https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dQ1nuBIHcJh8XhJP2aYUSlSc1VxJN-KA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean by "the result its same"? Do you mean "I do not see a different result when I compare `LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/wc --words arabian.txt` output in `shell_exec` and in a shell?"

Comment: @thatotherguy Sorry for not being clear. Result when using `LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/wc --words arabian.txt` is same as not using `LC_ALL=C ` in shell_exec, incorrect.

Comment: Which number do you see in `shell_exec` and which do you see in a shell for the same command with `LC_ALL=C` in front?

Comment: @thatotherguy you maybe are on to something. The number in shell_exec and in shell are same when using `LC_ALL=C` 1679

Comment: Then you can go to wherever it's correct and run `locale`, which will show some variables. Copy the value for `LC_CTYPE` and put it in front of your command, for example `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" /usr/bin/wc --words arabian.txt`. This should make the number match up with the correct one. Different languages and encodings have a different idea of what constitutes a word

Comment: @thatotherguy MAN, THANK YOU! I was thinking that I was going crazy, rechecked users and permissions a couple of times, and had no idea why it was working in shell and not in shell_exec.
Does `shell_exec` uses `LC_ALL=C` as default before running a command?
And how can I buy you a beer?

Comment: I posted a complete answer, accepting that is enough :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use the same locale, especially for the `LC_CTYPE` character encoding setting. Different languages have different ideas of what a word and non-word character is:

```
gnu/linux$ echo 'الدروس المستفادة من' | LC_CTYPE=C wc -w
0
gnu/linux$ echo 'الدروس المستفادة من' | LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" wc -w
3
```

You may also see this differ between versions of `wc`, here on macOS:

```
macos$ echo 'الدروس المستفادة من' | LC_CTYPE=C wc -w
   3
macos$ echo 'الدروس المستفادة من' | LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" wc -w
   5
```

It can sometimes be hard to predict which locale ends up being used, because it can be set by individual applications, by the user configuration, by system defaults, or even by settings on the system the user SSH'd from.

To see the current locale in effect, you can run `locale`. Copy the settings from there to make the numbers match up.